# Were there any non "misson-x" sets from the LEGO Alpha Team Range (as in with the PC Game)?

Tags: video-games, theme

In the LEGO Alpha Team Range, there's "Mission: Deep Sea" and "Misson: Deep Freeze", but were there any sets in the same "theme" as the computer game (and the same characters)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the original Alpha Team sets are the one's you're looking for, including the [LEGO Alpha Team Secret Mission Collectors Pack](http://brickset.com/detail/?Set=65118-1) which includes:

- [bs:6771] with Ogel
- [bs:6773] with Dash
- [bs:6774] with Cam and Flex

There are also:

- [bs:6772] with Radia
- [bs:6775] with Charge, Crunch and Tee Vee (a robot)
- [bs:6776] with Ogel and two minion commanders.

Comment: Ah, yes, that's it. I remember 6773 as I had that copter with the transparent rotors. I also remember Tee Vee from the video game, an interesting combination of minifigure legs, a computer screen, and an aerial.